# Why are the number of upvotes on an answer sometimes blue?

Tags: discussion, voting

So far I have seen these colors for up voted answers:

```
Green background, Yellow text - Accepted Answer
Grey background, Dark Grey text - Normal Answer
Grey background, Blue text - ???
```

When the number of votes a question has is in blue, what does that signify?

Edit: I have seen this again today and I'm still not convinced it's a glitch.

Comment: I've also seen Green background, Blue text, but it went away upon a page refresh.

Comment: Because they are sad... `:(`

Comment: If you see it again, could you provide a screenshot? I use Firefox on the SO sites and I don't know that I've seen this "glitch" before.

Comment: Whether or not it's a problem with Firefox or Stack Overflow itself doesn't really matter - it's still a glitch in the sense that it's not supposed to happen and doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Hmm, okay. If it isn't actually meant to mean anything I guess we can call this one case closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything actually.  It is just a [bug in Firefox.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-stackoverflow-colors-mean)

Comment: A bug... turns text blue?

Comment: I guess...I'm just passing what I read along.

Comment: If the bug is in the way it renders CSS, then why not?

Comment: It's kinda weird how it's only on some elements. Is there something that makes just those turn blue but not the others?

Comment: That explains why I fruitlessly searched for it in IE. I was worried already about getting blind ...

Comment: Haha, yeah, it is only in Firefox.

Comment: I've seen this so many times. I thought it had some meaning ^^

Comment: However, first of all this is a **BUG of Stackoweflow** in *Firefox*, not a Firefox bug in Stackoverflow... yeah.. :)

Comment: Still a bug in Firefox 3.5.7