# Why some tags score are in blue?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-score

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are the number of upvotes on an answer sometimes blue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/why-are-the-number-of-upvotes-on-an-answer-sometimes-blue)

[alt text http://lh6.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S0YDMSN-BoI/AAAAAAAAC4Y/P4ScXI2Z6XU/s800/blue.png](http://lh6.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/S0YDMSN-BoI/AAAAAAAAC4Y/P4ScXI2Z6XU/s800/blue.png)

Comment: Duplicate. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/why-are-the-number-of-upvotes-on-an-answer-sometimes-blue

Comment: It even appears when asking on the suggested list (although it's the fifth entry).