# Glitch in personal answers list color-coding

Tags: bug, status-declined, answers, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are the number of upvotes on an answer sometimes blue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3639/why-are-the-number-of-upvotes-on-an-answer-sometimes-blue)

There's a glitch in the user answers list. In the "What is the sanest.." question, there's an `<a>` link

[image: glitch]

This is the code for that case

`<div title="total number of votes for this answer, which was accepted as the correct answer by the question owner" class="answer-votes answered-accepted"><a href="/questions/2006960/what-is-the-sanest-way-to-use-global-variables-in-javascript/2006987#2006987">18</a></div>`

This is the code for the case directly below

`<div title="total number of votes for this answer, which was accepted as the correct answer by the question owner" class="answer-votes answered-accepted">15</div>`

So there's a spurious `<a>` for some reason, which is useless since the number is already linked (the `div` is already included into a parent `<a>`)

Comment: It might help to link which user you're seeing this on. That aside, I have seen this before a couple months back on some profile, but I don't know which.

Comment: For things like this, remember to note the browser you're subjecting yourself to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=457765).

That [color doesn't mean anything](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean).

[I don't see the bug in chrome.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcI3K.png)

[Or IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFFu4.png)

Comment: @Stefano, yeah...it s caused by a bug.

Comment: @Stefano, look at the bug report that I linked to...

Comment: @Stefano, if you read the link, you'll see that Firefox admitted that the " Anchor-element wrapped outside <li>-element gets duplicated inside it"

Comment: It's the same root cause @ste

Comment: @stefano, well, my guess is that the team has decided not to code a workaround for this little bug.

Comment: I have to agree - the actual Firefox bug doesn't seem to have any direct relationship to the problem - also, the Firefox bug was fixed months ago and this appears to still be happening.  I've just looked through all of the answers and history and none of it satisfactorily (to me) explains the behaviour, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Well, why does it only ever happen in Firefox?

Comment: Doesn't happen in **Opera** either. @ste

Comment: Ok guys, sorry. I got it! Apologies. (begs pardon)

Comment: @Stefano, no need to apologize.  The source in chrome looks correct.

Comment: There is, I just didn't focus on what you told me to read. Thanks again.

Comment: @stef, glad we got it all cleared up.